# Changing size of user avatar in template file

Tags: theming, media

In node.tpl I currently display a users avatar' using this code

```
theme('user_picture', $account)
```

My avatars are currently set to 85x85px but when they are displayed in nodes I want them to be smaller. How can I change the size for just this inclusion of user avatars?

Comment: Possible duplicate. I have similar question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5499/make-uploaded-image-thumbnail-bigger

Comment: @drupality good catch.  The solution is the same, however the other question says nothing about avatars and deals more direct with file uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although iStryker's suggestion works I found a simpler, easier to manage way.

I had to install imagecache and imagecache_profiles then I simply put this in my template (after creating a new preset in imagecache)

```
$account->imagecache_preset = 'NAME_OF_PRESET';         
print theme('user_picture', $account);
```

I did some googling after someone suggested Imagecache and found the above code here: http://drupal.org/node/374372

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely the command you want to run

```
theme('imagecache', 'your_custom_preset', $picture, $alt, $alt);
```

You will have to install imagecache module for Drupal 6.  Its in core for Drupal 7.   You have to define 'your_custom_preset', in the imagecache profiles.

The other place you can theme the avatar is inside the function
`[YOUR_THEME_NAME]_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables)`  and again use the same line as above. for more information checkout the [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/6) documention on this issue

Answer (score 1):

you can modify line modules/user/user.module line 425:

```
'file_validate_image_resolution' => array(variable_get('user_picture_dimensions', '85x85')),
```

or

create user-picture.tpl.php in your theme folder:

```
<div class="picture">
    <?php print $picture; ?>
</div>
```

and modify above code. use below code to understand what you should do:

```
global $user;
print_r($user);
```

Comment: Point #1.  Don't hack code!

Comment: Yes you are right :) even if you have not another way